# how can i get two values from one select option?

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm new in web development, I want to get two values from select option. Is this possible?

**HTML :**

```
<select name="position">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="100">Postion One</option>
    <option value="200">Postion Two</option>
    <option value="300">Postion Three</option>
</select>
```

Basically I want to create `dynamically layers` which will show on index page and positions are the alignment position. Above select positions are use as left position `"left:_______"`. But I need left as well as top position. I get left position from select option but how can get top position. I want to use only one select option for position in my form. So is there possible to get two positions (values) from one select option. Please help me.

Comment: you can add some data attribute like data-top="100" for each option. Then using jquery, you can use the onchange event to pick both the values - value and data-top.

Comment: is there possible to get values without jquery or javascript..?

Comment: i doubt there is any direct way to do that. Can you assign value for each option as - "200,100" and then pass it on to server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `multiple` attribute, and change the `name` to `position[]`.

```
<select name="position[]" multiple size="2">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="100">Postion One</option>
    <option value="200">Postion Two</option>
    <option value="300">Postion Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanx for response but how to get two value in php please add your php code